# Weird speed results for memoized fibonacci function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, memoization

I put together simple memoization example and run few performance tests but do not understand why on Chrome `memTestHalfAssed` is the fastest, even though `fibonacciH` calls inside are not memoized. Tests are at http://jsperf.com/moize-test

```
function fibonacci(n) {
    return n < 2 ? n : fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
}
Function.prototype.memoized = function(a) {

    if (typeof this.cache === "undefined")  this.cache = [];
    if (this.cache[a]) {
        return this.cache[a];
    } else {
        this.cache[a] = this(a);
        return this.cache[a];
    }
}

Function.prototype.memoize=function() {
  var t=this;
  return function() {
   return t.memoized.apply(t,arguments);
   //return t.memoized(arguments[0]);
  }
}

memTest= (function fibonacciM(n) {
    return n < 2 ? n : fibonacciM.memoized(n - 1) + fibonacciM.memoized(n - 2);
}).memoize();

memTestHalfAssed = (function fibonacciH(n) {
    return n < 2 ? n : fibonacciH(n - 1) + fibonacciH(n - 2);
}).memoize();
```

EDIT:

I updated the Revision 1 tests as per Gaffa's answer and now it seems to make more sense.

Comment: If you had to get the `50000+k`th value of the Fibonacci sequence (for small `k`) one million times, I think you might beg to differ.

Comment: @user2864740 could you please elaborate why fibonacci is such a bad example? What would be a better example? I'm not being a pest but genuinely want to know, thanks

Comment: @spirytus Because it's often taught as how memoziation can make things faster .. but (unless you're doing what JayC said *many* times), it's often more efficient [just to compute it smarter](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/The_Fibonacci_sequence).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why the `memTestHalfAsses` is faster in Chrome, but that can be some optimization that goes wrong in the cache access. Other browsers doesn't show this difference.

The test doesn't really measure the difference between the implementations, only how well the cache works when the value already is in the cache. The test code will be run millions of times, and it's only the first time that the execution will differ. After that both `memTest` and `memTestHalfAssed` will both return the cached value immediately.

To see the difference between them you would need to move the creation of `memTest` and `memTextHalfAssed` from the preparation code into the test code, or empty the cache of the functions in the test code.